# How shall I select a particular checkbox having ::before tag?

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, checkboxlist

I am not able to check the checkbox present in the table and having ::before tag, the selenium is always returning 'element not visible' error. tried putting wait implicit and explicit but it is not helping neither the action class (for list of elements) .Please help me select a particular checkbox from list of checckboxes, all the checkboxes are having ::before tag in HTML Dom.

I am using below xpath, for the checkboxes present in div data-table:

```
//label[@for='myCheckboxrCustom']);
```

I am using for loop and storing the value of Expense Type and Business Purpose in strings and then comparing these stored values to the expected values and when these values matches I am using if condition to select the checkbox. However, I am getting the "element not visible" error.

I have also tried using action class to move to a particular checkbox and then check it but it is only working for the first checkbox present in the table, not the second checkbox. Seems like the action class i have written is not working for list of elements

I am using java to select the second checkbox, having the expense type Meals.

Below is the HTML:

````
<div class="col-12 scrolling pend active" style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="title-table">   
        <div class="select">                       
            <input id="check-all" class="check-all" type="checkbox" autocomplete="on">
                <label for="check-all">
                    ::before
                </label>                      
        </div>      
        <div class="expense-type">Expense Type</div>        
        <div class="bus-purpose">Business Purpose</div>
    </div>    
    <div class="data-table ExpenseTransactionsDiv" referencetype="Actual" expdetailid="162341">
        <div class="select" data-title="Select: ">
            <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckboxr" name="chkExpenseDetailID" class="chkbox" value="162341" autocomplete="on">
                <label for="myCheckboxrCustom">
                    ::before
                </label>
        </div>
        <div class="expense-type" data-title="Expense Type">Meals</div>
        <div class="bus-purpose" data-title="Business Purpose">TC_4631</div>        
    </div>                           
    <div class="data-table ExpenseTransactionsDiv" referencetype="Actual" expdetailid="162337">
        <div class="select" data-title="Select: ">
            <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckboxr" name="chkExpenseDetailID" class="chkbox" value="162337" autocomplete="on">
            <label for="myCheckboxrCustom">
                ::before
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="expense-type" data-title="Expense Type">Hotel</div>              
        <div class="bus-purpose" data-title="Business Purpose">TC_4631</div>
    </div>
</div> 
```
````

Comment: There are 3 checkboxes, which one do you want to click?

Comment: the second one having the expense type Meals

Comment: Which language are you using? Java/Python/C#?

Comment: I am usinf java

Comment: Can you update the main question with all these additional information please?

Answer (score 0):

I used the code bellow on your example and I was able to check the box I wanted.

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="myCheckboxr"]').click()
```

You need to click on the input and not on the label element.

Comment: tried this one also, still element not visible error

Comment: Oh my answer is for python not java

Answer (score 0):

Apparently wait and action class combination resolved this issue:

```
List <WebElement> selectCheckbox = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//label[@for='myCheckboxrCustom"));
```

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.moveToElement(selectCheckbox ).click(selectCheckbox ).actions.build().perform();
```

Thanks guys for your inputs